# How to get delimiters of the same size when using fourier?

Tags: fourier

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools} 
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
    \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant\tau\left[\nu_{\sigma}^{Q}(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_i^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]+(1-\tau)\left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
\end{gather*}

\begin{gather*}
    \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant\tau\Bigg[\nu_{\sigma}^{Q}(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_i^{-1}}\sigma_k\Bigg]+(1-\tau)\left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

As you can see in the screenshot below, the squared parentheses of the two parts of the expression are not of the same size. I've been playing around to get them of the same size, but it turns out that I can only do so by commenting `\usepackage{fourier}`, something I would personally like to avoid. Using `\left[\right]` is too big (case 1), whereas using `\Bigg[\Bigg]` (the biggest I know) is not big enough (case 2).

[image]

My question is thus simple: how can I get them of the same size without dropping `\usepackage{fourier}`?

Thank you all very much for your time and effort.

Comment: You could use, for instance, `\renewcommand{\BIG}{\bBigg@{3}}`, then use `\BIG` instead.

Comment: <<case 2 id fine for me. I don't think delimiters have to encompass the totality of the sum symbol, including the indices.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for your comment. If it were an answer, I'd accept it...

Comment: @Bernard I certainly don't know if delimiters should encompass the totality of the sum symbol, but I for sure want the parentheses to be of the same size for what is left after $\tau$ and after $(1-\tau)$ (something which does not happen in either case). Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, but the simplest solution consists in using something like `\Biggl[ ... \Biggr]` in both cases.

Comment: And then refusing to use ``\left``and ``\right``because they are *too* large?

Comment: That's  a possibility. Personally, I very rarely use `left ...\right`.. The horizontal spacing is better.

Comment: Well, then it turns out that there are two really simple and valid answers to my question. Should we keep the question on the site? Also, why does this only happen with ``\usepackage{fourier}`` uncommented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is causing you this trouble is the `i` lowered a tad too much:

> [image]

There are a few approaches to overcome this and get the delimiter size you want. To name a few:

- You can `\smash` the `i` to make it have zero depth and height, then it won't be a problem anymore:

  ```
  \begin{equation*}
     \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant
        \tau \left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_{\smash{i}}^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
    +(1-\tau)\left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
  \end{equation*}
  ```
- You can also change TeX's `\delimiterfactor` and `\delimitershortfall` and let TeX adjust the delimiters accordingly:

  ```
  \begin{equation*}
     \delimitershortfall=7pt % Found by trial-and-error
     \delimiterfactor=810 % Move outside the `equation*` to make the effect global
     \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant
        \tau \left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_i^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
    +(1-\tau)\left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
  \end{equation*}
  ```
- Or you can define a new size with  `amsmath`'s (loaded by `mathtools`) `\bBigg@`. Note that simply using `\BIG` you get a different spacing around the delimiters.

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \def\BIG{\bBigg@{3}} % \big = 1; \Big = 1.5; \bigg = 2; and \Bigg = 2.5
  \def\BIGl{\mathopen\BIG}
  \def\BIGr{\mathclose\BIG}
  \makeatother

  \begin{equation*}
     \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant
        \tau \BIGl[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_i^{-1}}\sigma_k\BIGr]
    +(1-\tau)\BIGl[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\BIGr]
  \end{equation*}
  ```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
   \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant
      \tau \left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_i^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
  +(1-\tau)\left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
   \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant
      \tau \left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_{\smash{i}}^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
  +(1-\tau)\left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
   \delimitershortfall=7pt
   \delimiterfactor=810
   \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant
      \tau \left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_i^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
  +(1-\tau)\left[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\right]
\end{equation*}

\makeatletter
\def\BIG{\bBigg@{3}}
\def\BIGl{\mathopen\BIG}
\def\BIGr{\mathclose\BIG}
\makeatother

\begin{equation*}
   \sigma_i+\sigma_n\geqslant
      \tau \BIGl[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{i\})+\nu(R_i^{-1}\cup\{n\})-\sum_{k\in R_i^{-1}}\sigma_k\BIGr]
  +(1-\tau)\BIGl[\nu_{\sigma}^Q(\{n\})+\nu(R_n^{-1}\cup\{i\})-\sum_{k\in R_n^{-1}}\sigma_k\BIGr]
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Great answer, since it provides a few cool alternatives. Thank you!