# \left and \right not working on parentheses within the same line when internal fractions are changed

Tags: math-mode

I'm trying to show the product of two Legendre symbols. When I compile the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right) \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)$$
\end{document}
```

it yields

[image]

as expected. However, when I switch the variables, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$
\end{document}
```

it yields

[image]

How do I resolve this? Why do the values within the fractions matter?

Comment: The double signs of `$$` it is a old syntax. You should must `\[...\]`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/455336/134574).

The values in the fractions matter because the boxes of the characters have different sizes. The `p` has a descender below the baseline which the `x` doesn't, thus when you swap them, the box of the denominator get a little bigger and TeX uses a larger delimiter to make that fit.

You have a few possibilities to work around that (basically the same ones I listed in the linked question):

- You can use a fixed delimiter size (`\bigg` or `\Big`, for instance):

  ```
  $$\Bigl(\frac{x}{p}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{p}{x}\Bigr)$$
  $$\biggl(\frac{x}{p}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{p}{x}\biggr)$$
  ```
- You can `\raise` the `p` so that TeX won't try to use a larger box:

  ```
  $$\left(\frac{x}{\raise0.35ex\hbox{$p$}}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$
  ```
- or you can add an invisible `p` next to the `x` so that the delimiter used will be the larger one:

  ```
  $$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{\vphantom{p}x}\right)$$
  ```
- Or you can change change TeX's `\delimiterfactor` (and `\delimitershortfall`, which I didn't show here) and let TeX adjust the delimiters accordingly:

  ```
  $$\delimiterfactor=790
  \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$

  $$\delimiterfactor=970
  \left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$
  ```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
% \delimitershortfall=5pt % Default
% \delimiterfactor=901    % Default

$$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$

$$\Bigl(\frac{x}{p}\Bigr)\Bigl(\frac{p}{x}\Bigr)$$
$$\biggl(\frac{x}{p}\biggr)\biggl(\frac{p}{x}\biggr)$$

$$\left(\frac{x}{\raise0.35ex\hbox{$p$}}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$

$$\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{\vphantom{p}x}\right)$$

$$\delimiterfactor=790
\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$

$$\delimiterfactor=970
\left(\frac{x}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{x}\right)$$
\end{document}
```

Output:

> [image]

Answer (score 13):

Use `\genfrac` for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\genlegendre}[3]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\legendre}[2]{\genlegendre{}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\dlegendre}[2]{\genlegendre{0}{#1}{#2}}
\newcommand{\tlegendre}[2]{\genlegendre{1}{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\[
\legendre{x}{p}\quad\legendre{p}{x}\quad
\legendre{x}{x}\quad\legendre{d}{b}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The variants `\dlegendre` and `\tlegendre` are analogous to `\dfrac` and `\tfrac`.

Comment: I've never heard of `\tfrac`, what's the package that defines it?

Comment: @AndréC `amsmath`, along with `\dfrac`; also `\binom`, `\dbinom` and `\tbinom`. In some cases, in displays `\tfrac` is needed not to give prominence to fractional factors.

Answer (score 0):

I like the unified syntax for this kind of stuff in the `mathtools` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{\lparen}{\rparen}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \paren*{\frac{x}{p} }\quad \paren*{\frac{p}{x}}
  \qquad
  \paren[\bigg]{\frac{x}{p}} \quad \paren[\bigg]{\frac{p}{x}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]