# inverting fraction comes out different size

Tags: math-mode, fractions, parentheses

I think I get why the two parentheses/fractions here are not the same size:

```
\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)
```

Screenshot from Mathjax website:

[image: ja]

Presumably something about the baseline being different for p and for 3.  But at the same time, it just looks bad.  Notice that `\frac{3}{p}\frac{p}{3}` or `(\frac{3}{p})(\frac{p}{3})` look better, but I need parentheses here and I'd prefer them to cover the whole fraction (actually, Legendre symbol).  Can anyone think of a better way to do this?

Comment: MathJaX is generally off-topic in this site. The problem, however, is the same as in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461582/134574

Comment: As Phelype mentions MathJaX has nothing to do with LaTeX and friends. It is just a javascript library that attempts to render a subset of LaTeX syntax. If it does something wrong, you probably need to talk to the mathjax people about it. LaTeX people cannot do anything about it as it does not use LaTeX.

Comment: I didn't know MJ was OT, but in any case I did this just to show the result.  MJ is very nice and pretty faithful, and a lot easier to try out than creating a full document!

Comment: But yes I agree this is a dup.

Comment: Why was I allowed to vote to close my own question?  Is there another way to do that? I don't know if self-deleting it is the proper path here - unless there is some obscure badge for doing that, wouldn't be surprised ...

Comment: @kcrisman I think if someone suggests the duplicate you can accept it. I don't know about you suggesting it (I didn't because I was not sure if it was duplicate or off-topic).

Comment: Yeah, it's not OT because it wasn't really about MJ, sorry about that.